# When flatmates get an AVO against each other, who has to move out?

Tags: criminal-law, australia, family-law, new-south-wales, domestic-abuse

If one flatmate trespasses in another’s room after an extended period of hostile verbal and nonverbal communication, can the flatmate who was trespassed against get an AVO? If so, who has to move out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, an order would specify what happens. There is no hard and fast rule in this situation.